# Can't compile material-components with webpack-encore

Tags: symfony, symfony4, material-components, webpack-encore

`yarn encore dev` fail after setting up `material-components`

I installed `material-components` using `yarn add material-components-web --dev`

and then configured `app.js` like this :

```
/* --- CSS --- */
import "../css/normalize.scss";
import "material-components-web/material-components-web.scss"
import "../css/layout.scss";
import "../css/style.scss";

/* --- RESOURCES ---*/
import $ from "jquery";
import * as mdc from "material-components-web";
```

When running `yarn encore dev`, I get the following error :

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                                          22:30:40

 error  in ./node_modules/material-components-web/material-components-web.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

@import "@material/elevation/mixins";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: @material/elevation/mixins.
      in /var/www/vhosts/salon-virtuel/node_modules/@material/button/_mixins.scss (line 23, column 1)
    at runLoaders (/var/www/vhosts/salon-virtuel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:301:20)
    at /var/www/vhosts/salon-virtuel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /var/www/vhosts/salon-virtuel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/var/www/vhosts/salon-virtuel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.render [as callback] (/var/www/vhosts/salon-virtuel/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:52:13)
    at Object.done [as callback] (/var/www/vhosts/salon-virtuel/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:8077:18)
    at options.error (/var/www/vhosts/salon-virtuel/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:294:32)

 @ ./assets/js/app.js 7:0-62

Entrypoint app [big] = runtime.js vendors~app.js app.css app.js
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

**Imports in files :**

<kbd>**node_modules/material-components-web/material-components-web.scss**</kbd>

```
@import "@material/elevation/mdc-elevation";
```

<kbd>**node_modules/@material/elevation/mdc-elevation.scss**</kbd>

```
@import "./mixins";
@include mdc-elevation-core-styles;
```

<kbd>**node_modules/@material/elevation/_mixins.scss**</kbd>

```
@import "@material/feature-targeting/functions";
@import "@material/feature-targeting/mixins";
@import "@material/theme/variables";
@import "./variables";
```

Any idea about why it's happening, and how to fix this?

Comment: Can you check in @material/elevation/mixins if the file is really called "mixins" and not "_mixins" ?

Comment: Have you tried renaming mixins to _mixins or change the @import to _mixins instead of mixins ? Google do not use the default scss semantics so it's quite annoying at times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are very close. Try to edit your encore config to include node_modules to sass loader like this:

```
// enables Sass/SCSS support
.enableSassLoader(function(options) {
    // https://github.com/sass/node-sass#options
    options.includePaths = ['./node_modules'];
}, {
    // set optional Encore-specific options
    // resolve_url_loader: true
});
```

explained [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)

Comment: Indeed, was the problem. CSS compile fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For the case, someone else stumbles over this.
It may would have also solved your issue, if you changed the way how you import the scss/sass files.

```
@import "~@material/feature-targeting/functions";
@import "~@material/feature-targeting/mixins";
@import "~@material/theme/variables";
@import "./variables";
```

The `~` references the node_modules as well. That is at least how I do it and it works without any special config for the sass-loader.

Comment: And next time you `npm install` it all breaks again

Comment: It never broke for me when I ran npm ci or npm install. Why would or should it?